# How to refresh the terminal after yarn installation

Tags: bash

I am absolutely new to coding, so my question will sound absolutely silly. I am trying to setup yarn on Ubuntu 18.04 vps, and I installed it with '''curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash'''
It was installed successfully, yet it now asks me to:  >Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.
And for my unsustainable shame, I, truly, have no idea how to do it. Would be great to hear your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Close the current Terminal by clicking on the little x in the corner, then in Activities type in Terminal clicking on the icon that appears to open new one.